# How to move N lines from one file to another

Tags: 16.04, server, cron, wget

I want to download multiple files, so I decided to create 4 text files that are handled with a script.

```
toDownload.txt | this file will hold a list of links to download.
inQueue.txt    | the files currently downloading will move here and if failed we can continue later using wget -c flag.
downloaded.txt | this file will hold file links that have finished downloading.
failed.txt     | this file will hold links that failed to start downloading for example if the URL returns 404.
```

**how can I move the first x number of links from a file and move it to another file?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

lines=3
head -n $lines file1.txt >> file2.txt
sed -i -e "1,$lines d" file1.txt
```

This will append the first three lines from `file1.txt` to `file2.txt`
and then delete the lines 1…3 from `file1.txt` effectively
moving the first 3 lines from `file1.txt` to the end of `file2.txt`.